# Add node module to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, node-modules

I am currently tying to add this single node module to my chrome extension: https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-urls Except I always get the require is not defined error. I have googled this and all I have been able to find are chrome extension templates to use but those give them same require is not defined error as well (and they are confusing to set up). I have built a chrome extension before using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuse.js/v/3.4.3 module.  I was able to get it to work by adding it into the manifest.json file like this:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["node_modules/fuse.js/dist/fuse.js", "background.js"]
}
```

But I am unable to do this with the get-urls file as the index.js file has require() in it.

```
'use strict';
const {URL} = require('url');
const urlRegex = require('url-regex');
const normalizeUrl = require('normalize-url');
```

When I npm installed the get-urls It also installed the folders that all these things are requiring. My question is will I be able to add the node_modules path to each index.js file and remove the require at the top of the files? each index.js file is requiring each other so they are all connected.

Is there an easier way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: Node is separate from the web. They are different runtimes; Node explicitly provides a `require` function for you to use modules and packages. You *can* look into webpack, but form the looks of it this code could be implemented with web APIs.

Comment: @Li357 Are you suggesting I create an api that uses the node modules and just call to it from the chrome extension?

Comment: No. I'm saying you could probably make the functionality of `get-url` without Node. By web APIs I mean technologies available in the browser environment. You can use URL which is a global object. Or the library might even have a browser build, or there might be other libraries with similar functionality that do.

Comment: See also [Is it possible to require npm modules in a chrome extension ?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43684452)